# Change reports text for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, naming

I have a report style document:

```
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
```

and when I do:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

it shows :

**Bibliography** instead of **References**

Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the packages which are loaded.

If you don't use the package `babel` you can redefine the command `\bibname` as usual.

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
```

If you are using a `documentclass` of the type `article` you must redefine the command `\refname`. The procedure is equal.

If you load `babel` you can use the command above but only in the document body. To redefine in the header you must use:

```
\addto\captions<languagename>{\renewcommand\bibname{References}}
```

For example for `ngerman` it looks:

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\bibname{References}}
```

A whole example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
%\renewcommand\bibname{References} doesn't work
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\bibname{References}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={Title},
year=2009,
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to include it in the toc as well?

Comment: You can load the package `tocbibind`