# using biblatex -formatting References section

Tags: biblatex, indentation

I am studying `biblatex` and I'm using just a basic file...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

%\labelnamepunct
\addbibresource{animation}

\begin{document}

he said this \footcite{Branston2006}
...
and he said that\parencite{Branston2006}

Edwards\footcite{Edwards2005}

Hammel\footcite{Hammel2007}

Hornung\footcite{Hornung2005}

Maestri\footcite{Maestri1996}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which gives me the References section. But with the second line of each reference INDENTED.

1. How can I get rid of that indentation so that it simply flows on to the next line?
2. How can I rename the 'References' section to 'List of References'?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "`{}`" on it).

Comment: Please have a look at the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27596/change-reports-text-for-bibliography/27599#27599
You can also use `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    references = {List of References}
}`

Answer (score 8):

Because you're using the `article` document class, you should insert the following command in your document's preamble in order to change the caption of the References section to "List of References":

```
\renewcommand\refname{List of References}
```

(If you were using the `book` or `report` document class, you'd type `\renewcommand\bibname{List of References}`.) Second, in order to suppress the hanging indentation of the second and subsequent lines of bibliography items, you should add the command

```
\setlength\bibhang{0pt} % default value: \parindent
```

to the preamble, after loading `biblatex`. Happy (bibla)TeXing!

Comment: `\bibname` is defined in *book/report*, while `\refname` is defined in *article*.

Comment: @lockstep: I linked to an previous question.

Comment: @lockstep -- many thanks for spotting this permutation error! I've corrected the answer.