# AAAI bibtex style with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Conferences whose proceedings are published by the American Association for Artificial Intelligence ([AAAI](http://aaai.org)) usually demand authors to use the AAAI [latex package](https://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php). The package provides a bibtex `.bst` file, with no apparent support for `biblatex`.

Here is a minimal example showing the result obtained with the official `bibtex` style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @article{Stark04,
    author    = {T. Stark},
    title     = {{M}aintaining {K}nowledge about {W}eaponry},
    journal   = {International Journal of Armored Weapons},
    volume    = {26},
    number    = {11},
    pages     = {832--843},
    year      = {2004}
  }

  @incollection{Riddle94,
    author      = {T. M. Riddle},
    title       = {{I}ntegrating {P}otions and {D}eath {E}aters},
    editor      = {Mary Zen and Mark S. Furling},
    booktitle   = {Intelligent Magic},
    publisher   = {Morgan Kaufmann},
    year        = 1994,
    pages       = {169--212},
    chapter     = 6
  }

  @inproceedings{LutorK17,
    author    = {L. Lutor and C. Kent},
    title     = {
      {On The Effects of Mineral Mining from Alien Planets}
    },
    booktitle = {
      {Proc. of the 31st {AAAI} Conference on Alien
      Intelligence}
    },
    pages     = {3547--3554},
    year      = {2017}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\title{How to be published on comics and fantasy books}
\author{Stan Lee}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

It is always good to cite \cite{Riddle94,Stark04} and acknowledge
\cite{LutorK17}.

\lipsum[1-5]

\bibliographystyle{aaai}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}


\end{document}
```

The citation style itself is like `(Author Name et al. 1999)`, while the bibliography is rendered in the normal way, I suppose. The example shows a conference paper, a collection chapter and a journal article.

[image: example]

Is there some unofficial AAAI `biblatex` style out there to obtain the same results, or can you suggest me how to configure `biblatex` to obtain the same bibliography appearance (the citation style is quite standard)?

Comment: The style is more or less `\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]biblatex` but if you are submitting to AAAI you should use their style. Why do you want to change?

Comment: `biblatex` is more convenient to use for authoring, commands are more flexible and configurable. The style is ok, I don't want to change how it appears. Anyway, they don't care which is the actual code used to produce the output as long as it looks the same, and even if they cared, they'd only care at the time of submission of the camera-ready copy, not initially.

Comment: Mhhh, the flexibility of `biblatex` is not really of use if you have to switch back to the provided `.bst` file later. [Most publishers really can't handle `biblatex`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) Given the fact that there is a `.bst` by the publisher it is unlikely that there is a `biblatex` copy of it. So you are asking us to provide the full style for you. I don't think that is a particular well suited request at this side, but questions like this have been answered before.

Comment: ... But if you want us to help you we really need to know what exactly we need to change if you start with say `style=authoryear-icomp`. I don't want to spend hours analysing the AAAI style for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only a starting point, not a complete answer, it's also an occasion to explain how to ask a `biblatex` question.

Starting from the standard `authoryear-icomp`, I've added the code to:

- remove the `:` after `In`
- remove the parentheses from the year in the bibliography
- remove the quote marks from titles
- remove `pp` from pages in the bibliography
- put a comma before `and` in the author list
- invert last and first names of the second author
- avoid reference indentation
- put a bit of vertical space between the bibitems.

You can find most of that solutions in other posts here on TeX.SE, by the way.

A lot of things remain to do, but you can ask specific questions on them (searching before if they are not duplicates), as a follow-up of your question. For a trivial example: *how to write `chapter` instead of `Chap.`?*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

% to leave out the : after In
% see moewe's first comment
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

% to leave out the () around the year in bibliography
% (code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40710/101651)
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
    \printtext[parens]%
}{%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printtext%
}{}{}

% to remove the quote marks around titles
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1}   
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}    
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1} 

% to remove pp before pages in bibliography
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    page             = {\ifbibliography{}{p\adddot}},
    pages            = {\ifbibliography{}{pp\adddot}},
} 

% to put a comma before the and in author list
% see moewe's comments, the second one also for alternative solutions
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

% to invert last and first names in second author
% (code from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151827/101651)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% to avoid reference indentation
% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37775/101651
\setlength\bibhang{0pt} % default value: \parindent

% a bit of vertical space between items
\setlength\bibitemsep{.2\baselineskip} 

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @article{Stark04,
        author    = {T. Stark},
        title     = {{M}aintaining {K}nowledge about {W}eaponry},
        journal   = {International Journal of Armored Weapons},
        volume    = {26},
        number    = {11},
        pages     = {832--843},
        year      = {2004}
    }

    @incollection{Riddle94,
        author      = {T. M. Riddle},
        title       = {{I}ntegrating {P}otions and {D}eath {E}aters},
        editor      = {Mary Zen and Mark S. Furling},
        booktitle   = {Intelligent Magic},
        publisher   = {Morgan Kaufmann},
        year        = 1994,
        pages       = {169--212},
        chapter     = 6
    }

    @inproceedings{LutorK17,
        author    = {L. Lutor and C. Kent},
        title     = {
            {On The Effects of Mineral Mining from Alien Planets}
        },
        booktitle = {
            {Proc. of the 31st {AAAI} Conference on Alien
                Intelligence}
        },
        pages     = {3547--3554},
        year      = {2017}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\title{How to be published on comics and fantasy books}
\author{Stan Lee}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    It is always good to cite \textcite{Riddle94,Stark04} and acknowledge
    \textcite{LutorK17}.

    \lipsum[1-5]

    \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of the redefinition of `in:` it is easier to go with `\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}`. I would not hard-code the `and` in `\finalnamedelim`, I'd have used `\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}`, but that requires an `.lbx` file that sets the Oxford comma. `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` should be `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` in `biblatex` >= 3.3.

Comment: 1) `in` --> done; 2) Oxford comma --> not done because I don't know how to do it; 3) `family-given` --> done. Thank you!

Comment: For the Oxford comma you could use the definition from my comment and `\usepackage[american]{babel}` (`american` sets the Oxford comma), or use `\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{\def\finalandcomma{\addcomma}}`, or go with `\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space\‌​bibstring{and}\space‌​}`