# How to show a different section title than 'References' for the reference list?

Tags: bibliographies, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the “References” to “Reference” in the thebibliography environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/how-can-i-change-the-references-to-reference-in-the-thebibliography-environm)
>   [Change reports text for bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27596/change-reports-text-for-bibliography)

I am writing my CV in LaTeX and I am using BibTeX to easily show all my publications. As resume jargon uses the term 'References' at the group of people they can get in touch with to ask about me I was wondering if I could change the title of the section of 'References' for something like 'Selected Publications'. My document class is `article`.

Comment: The best would be to add a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) to your question. But it should suffice if you just indicate the document class.

Comment: The document class is letterpaper

Comment: what document class are you using?  look in it to see if it defines `\refname`.  if it does, then you can just say `\renewcommand{\refname}{Selected Publications}`.  (not posting this as an answer as it has already probably been asked, but i don't have time to search for duplicates.)

Comment: `letterpaper` is a paper size, not a document class. We're after `\documentclass[..]{<this>}`.

Comment: You may be after `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Selected Publications}`. If so, this is a duplicate: [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12597/5764). Please see if this solves your problem and report back.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new in latex, The document class is article

Comment: Thanks for your time and answers. 

what worked was
`\renewcommand{\refname}{Selected Publications}`