# Bibliography title fontsize problem with BibTeX and the natbib package

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, fontsize, natbib

I'm trying to change the fontsize of the Bibliography title to a normal size but I can't do it.

I already try (without results):

```
\let\chapter=\chapter

\let\chapter=\section %works, but all the other section titles changes too and it's a mess

\renewcommand{\biblistfont}{
\normalfont
\normalsize}

% this last one show an error
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
\titleformat{\chapter} {\normalfont\tiny\filcenter\bfseries}{}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{60pt}{18pt}
\chapter*{ \bibname \markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}%
```

Also, this others commands to change the title name are not working (I want NEW TITLE instaed of New Title):

```
\renewcommand\bibname{New Title}
\renewcommand\refname{New Title}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{New Title}}
```

Here is a minimal example of my code:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,11pt]{book}
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{bla}
 Bla bla bla
 \section{bla bla}
 Bla bla bla

 \bibliographystyle{my style}
 \bibliography{my bib}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: So you want to change the default title "Bibliografía" so that the new title is something different ("Mi Título") written in normal size (10pt), and boldfaced? Should it start in a new page (as a default chapter) or not? Please explain all the details.

Comment: Yes that is;

I wanted in normal size, upper case, at the left, starting in a new page as default chapter, and I want it more closer to the top of the page too. But the most important thing is to reduce the size; the rest is secundary.

Comment: I've provided an answer below. Please process my example document and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, using a redefinition of `\bibsection`, as **Marco Daniel** suggested in his answer:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblioprueba.bib}
@misc{patashnik,
    author  = "Oren Patashnik",
    title   = "{BibTeX}ing.  {D}ocumentation for General {BibTeX} users",
    year    = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX distribution"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand\mybibname{New Title}
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
   \clearpage
   \noindent\normalsize\MakeUppercase{\mybibname}%
   \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\mybibname}}{\MakeUppercase{\mybibname}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}
 Bla bla bla
 \section{bla bla}
 Bla bla bla

\cite{patashnik}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblioprueba}

\end{document}
```

The code before `\documentclass` in my example code is just to provide you with a ready to use .bib file so you can simply copy-paste my code as it is and process it in the usual way using `(pdf)latex+bibtex+(pdf)latex+(pdf)latex` and see the result.

Comment: Yes, that is! thank you! I tried on my document too and it works; Where can I find a good manual/tutorial about this? I don't understand what you did even when it is about the same as Marco said

Comment: @Álvaro: You're welcome. Do you mean a manual for `natbib` of for LaTeX in general? By the way, since my answer seems to have solved your problem, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count).

Comment: I mean a manual to understand what you did :)

Comment: @Álvaro: well, all I did was to redefine a command. Perhaps the [lshort](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/spanish) document (I assumed, based on your name, that you can read Spanish) or the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) can be useful for you as introductory free tutorials. If you prefer a more advanced one, just say so.

Answer (score 2):

Your first and second listing are only copy-paste solution which can't work.

A simple way is the redefinition of `\bibsection` defined by `natbib`:

```
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
   \section*{New Title}%
   \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}%
  }%
```

Now I want to say something to your listings. The first one uses `titleformat`. To understand this you should read the documentation of `titlesec`

The redefinition of `\bibname` or `\refname` depends on the document class. This is explained here: [Change reports text for bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27596/change-reports-text-for-bibliography/27599#27599)

Comment: It's not working... the name still the same. I read the titlesec manual but I'm not a LaTeX expert and I don't understand all the information. But more than the text, I want to change the fontsize.

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of a font in a LaTeX documents use a new font size parameter like `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, `\Huge`.

To change the text size of the BibTeX part to small this hack worked out for me:

```
\begin{document}
    [...]

    %References
    \small{ 
        \bibliographystyle{natlib}
        \bibliography{mybiblio}
    }
\end{document}
```

compile, and keep on rocking in a free world.

Comment: That will change the font size of the bibliography.  However, the question was how to change the size of the heading for the bibliography.