# TOC: part name in center with out page number

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

I want to put part name in center of TOC as MODULE - I with out page number.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Module}%

\usetocstyle{standard}
%\settocfeature{pagenumberhook}{}
\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering#2}}% original #1 in second argument
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A}
\chapter{chapter A}
\section{Section a}
\lipsum
\part{B}
\chapter{chapter B}
\section{Section b}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redefining `l@part` you can hack `l@part` with `\addtokomafont`:

`\addto\captionsenglish` is used to redefine the partname. See: [Change reports text for bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27596/change-reports-text-for-bibliography)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
 \renewcommand{\partname}{Module}%
}

\makeatletter
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\def\numberline#1{--~#1\autodot\quad}\centering\partname~}
\addtokomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\let\hfil\relax\def\hb@xt@#1#2{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{A}
\chapter{chapter A}
\section{Section a}
\lipsum
\part{B}
\chapter{chapter B}
\section{Section b}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to format TOC with tocstyle when i use above.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `\l@part` as implemented in `scrbook.cls`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand\partname{Module}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{2em}%
    \if@tocleft
      \ifx\toc@l@number\@empty\else
        \setlength\@tempdima{0\toc@l@number}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \leavevmode
      \centering\usekomafont{partentry}{\partname\ -- #1\nobreak
        \usekomafont{partentrypagenumber}{}}\null\par
      \ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
      \endgroup
      \penalty20010
      \else
          \penalty\@highpenalty
      \endgroup
    \fi
  \fi
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Test Part One} 
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}
\part{Test Part Two} 
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to format TOC with tocstyle when i use above code.

Comment: @sandu that's not enough information. If you want to, you can edit your original question and add there a simple document showing the relevant settings you are using (those for tocstyle`) and showing the problems with the proposed solutions.

Comment: MWE is added in the question

Comment: Solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122373/how-to-remove-page-number-in-toc-for-part-entry-not-page-number-printed-in-toc?noredirect=1#comment273682_122373

Comment: @sandu I don't understand.  If you already solved the problem, then there's no need for the comments nor for the edit. Please rollback the edit to your question and leave it ss it initially was. Had I known about the other questio I wouldn't have suggested the edit in the first place.